# Calculating phase angles from symmetrical components

Tags: three-phase

I'm getting the following values from a meter:

```
NegSeqMag   40397.95    
NegSeqPhs   0.4087467   

PosSeqMag   229.4626    
PosSeqPhs   -134.8785   

ZeroSeqMag  132.43  
ZeroSeqPhs  -66.25984
```

I've watched these videos trying to understand how it works (I'm not an electrical engineer):

- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=s_mslfzRJzQ
- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8hG8XwbLsw8

Based on that, I tried the following:

$$va_{angle} = ZeroSeqPhs + PosSeqPhs + NegSeqPhs $$
$$vb_{angle} = ZeroSeqPhs + 240 + PosSeqPhs + 120 + NegSeqPhs $$
$$vc_{angle} = ZeroSeqPhs + 120 + PosSeqPhs + 240 + NegSeqPhs $$

However, the results do not seem correct. How can I calculate the phase angles?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I found my mistake: I was not considering the magnitude, therefore, not treating  it as a complex number.